# How to make a searchable dropdown that allows multiple values in flutter?

Tags: select, flutter, dart, dropdown, searchable

I'm looking on how to create a dropdown with multiple select options that also allows to search the values.
The expected result is like the Autocomplete Multiple Values of Material UI component.

I couldn't find something related and I was wondering if there is a package or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this 
[multiple_select](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_select)  package, that has a searcher inside. Hope it helps to the community.

Comment: Now, this plugin is incompatible with Dart 3. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use flutter_typeahead

```
    TypeAheadField(
  textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select Items'),
  ),
  suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
    // Implement a function to provide suggestions based on the search pattern.
    // You can fetch suggestions from your data source (e.g., a list or API).
    // Return a list of suggestions that match the pattern.
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
    // Build the suggestion item UI based on the suggestion.
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(suggestion),
    );
  },
  onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
    // Handle the selection of a suggestion.
    // Add the selected value to your list of selected items.
  },
  keepSuggestionsOnLoading: false,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the [autocomplete_textfield package](https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield)

[source to how to actually implement one](https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-auto-complete-search-list-a8dd192bd5f6).

Comment: is important that it allows to add multiple values. I found this  [package](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown) that is similar to the expected result I want, but it only accepts one value. Maybe you can check it and give me a suggestion.